# "do not do this" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

So this has come up a couple of times, should we have a "do not do this" tag? For questions like [copying the .sty files to PWD](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14192/215) or [renewing `\thesection` to remove section number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14234/215)

Answer (score 13):

Although I suggested this in chat, I was being a little facetious.  I think that this comes under the same rules as "best practices" and similar "meta" tags.  If there is a situation where one thinks, "Yes, that is *technically* possible, but your life is going to be much easier if you don't do that.", then I think that an "answer" explaining why the whatever-it-is shouldn't be done would be much better.  The questioner may not have known that there was a better way and just putting [dont-do-this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dont-do-this) on it would be a bit rude.  Better to say, "If you're trying to achieve *X* then a better way would be *Y* because *Z*.".  That also means that you don't look an idiot when they reply, "Actually, I know all about *Y* and *Z*, but I want to do *X* because of *W*." (where *W* is actually some bizarre but perfectly valid reason for doing *X*).

Comment: Maybe the tag should be called [tag:worst-practices] (also being facetious)

Comment: correct, this is a meta-tag. It cannot stand alone, you could not have (and would not want) a question tagged *only* [worst-practices]

Comment: And while we are at in, we also need {missing-mwe}, {incomprehensible-english} and {op-is-a-noob} ;-) Seriously, the answer to a question should not be given in a tag, but in the answer form.

Comment: @Caramdir: +1, however the idea of a {missing-mwe} tag popped into my mind already a couple of times.

Answer (score 6):

I'm against such a tag.

- It's not a meaningful category.
- It doesn't build a relationship between subjects besides telling there's something wrong
- I doubt anybody would use this for filtering or look-up.
- Who should be interessted in following the tag, who would use the tag to find questions he could answer?
- Answers are more about doing sth. than questions, it's more likely that an answer might deserve such a sign.

If somebody posts a question or an answer and thinks it deserves such a sign, he could choose a symbol for that, usable both in questions and answers. Other people could suggest such a sign by writing a comment.

An example, found on [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Ambox_warning_yellow.svg/40px-Ambox_warning_yellow.svg.png): [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely be ready to apply it to some of my *own* questions. Although I can understand that tagging someone else's question like that would not be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

diy.stackexchange has a [dangerous] tag, useful for things like: electrical work on live wiring, DIY asbestos removal, use of non-rated connectors with gas appliances, operation of chainsaws while naked, etc.

Comment: The thing is, a {dangerous} tag here should probably apply to things like malicious use of write18...

Comment: @Seamus: Good point. There is already a (non very often used) {security} tag which could also be used. However, {dangerous} would signal it better to the user!