# Do we need a [beauty-alert] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I accept that this question is similar to ["do not do this"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/do-not-do-this-tag), but please hear me out.

TeX is, at least in part, about *beautiful* typesetting. Now, although *beauty* is subjective, there are a number of commonly-agreed things that are generally considered *ugly*, and I believe that one of the measures of TeX.SX's "improvement of the Internet" is a question of beauty.

The idea of a [beauty-alert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beauty-alert) tag would be to act as a flag to tell the questioner that what she is trying to do may result in something that is less than beautiful -- a sort of "beware of what you wish for".

Of course, I don't insist on that tag name. I *did* think it a bit better than my original [blecch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blecch), [ugliness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ugliness), and [ugly-alert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ugly-alert) ideas, as it looks positive, rather than negative, but I'm open to suggestions.

The tag description text would need careful crafting. Here's a starter:

> What you are trying to do may be possible with TeX, but many,
>   experienced, typographers think that the results are less beautiful
>   than they otherwise might be. Please reconsider why you need to do
>   this; but, of course, go ahead if you believe you're right.

Comment: When I read [beauty-alert], I thought it was for flagging specially beauty answers. While I like the idea, I think a different name would be better. Probably [Comic Sansy], [borderline ugly] or [highly questionable] instead :D

Comment: We already have {best-practices}, which should show people the right direction (though we may want to add a few general questions with comprehensive answers there). I would go against your proposal because someone usually explains why something is a bad practice in one of the top comments/answers, and because many people don't really have a choice (some are forced to implement ugly styles with typographically insane rules, which must have been randomly created by people who had never actually opened a book in their entire lives).

Comment: meta-tags are strongly discouraged, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302/our-set-of-tags and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Similar to the linked question, I vote against such a tag.

Let's consider some points:

- Is it a meaningful category?
- Is is useful for filtering or look-up?
- Which tag features to we need? Such as following the tag RSS feed?

Looking at the idea:

> The idea of a beauty-alert tag would be to act as a flag to tell the
>   questioner that what she is trying to do may result in something that
>   is less than beautiful

So the intention is just using it as a sign. So we might use a sign, a colorful symbol in the question perhaps, but not an additional tag - because tags are more than just a word list below the question.

Comment: My first attempt: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w84mF.png `:)`

Comment: Much more sensible than my suggestion. Thank you. I like the idea of editing to add a sign.

Comment: I ♥ @Paulo.​​​​

Comment: @doncherry: */blushes* `:)`

Comment: I guess the tag would have all the same objections as there were to the do not do this tag.